# RN2483 PCB Layout

Tags: rf, pcb-design, layout, pcb-layers, via

I am designing a board based on RN2483. As i have none experience on **RF design** i am following the guidelines from microchip's datasheet as the pictures bellow.
[image]

[image]

So my question is about the many vias. I have seen another RF designs based on Semtech's sx1276, which is used in RN2483, and i observe the same vias pattern. Moreover, on an another sx1276 design under the IC (on the bottom layer) there is a similarly via pattern creating a square from vias as the dimensions of the IC.

**What is the purpose/gain of them?**

Comment: Go google "stitching vias and RF".

Comment: Many thanks for your comment. Do you know if there is a problem if i use common via instead of stitching one? I read the definition of stitching vias and their purpose on rf designs and i think it would not be any differences.